# mysql multiple where clause not working

Tags: mysql

Based on this table

```
 key    sampleID     rs         A1       A2  
 1     12345       rs123      C        C
 2     12345       rs345      C        C
 3     11110       rs123      C        C
 4     11110       rs345      C        A
```

This statement

```
SELECT sampleID 
FROM QS_base 
WHERE (rs = 'rs123' AND A1 = 'C' AND A2 = 'C') 
OR (rs = 'rs345' AND A1 = 'C' AND A2 = 'C')
```

Returns

```
12345
12345
11110
```

And this statement

```
SELECT sampleID 
FROM QS_base 
WHERE (rs = 'rs123' AND A1 = 'C' AND A2 = 'C') 
AND (rs = 'rs345' AND A1 = 'C' AND A2 = 'C')
```

Returns no records. I expected it to return

```
 12345
 12345
```

Why is it retuning no results and is there a way to write it so that the above result can be obtained?

Comment: It will not return because you are using `AND` operator at a time single row can not have both the values `rs = 'rs123'` and `rs = 'rs345'`. If you want distinct values then use `Distinct` in select.

Comment: Union is also a good option.

Comment: @CoderofCode thanks but wont distinct remove duplicates?

Comment: You updated the output. By first output you wanted single value that's why used `DIstinct`. You can look at the @Gordon or @Abhik answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get what you want using `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT sampleID 
FROM QS_base 
WHERE (rs = 'rs123' AND A1 = 'C' AND A2 = 'C') OR
      (rs = 'rs345' AND A1 = 'C' AND A2 = 'C')
GROUP BY sampleID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT rs) = 2;
```

Comment: that removes the duplicates but I need it to satisfy both criteria, ie the clause has to be AND rather than OR.

Comment: You can use IN clause. But You can not filter the table You provided basing only on columns RS,A1 and A2. The combination of values are the same. [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e5c5/2) is fiddle example.

Comment: @gungu . . . The `having` clause ensures that both conditions are met.

Comment: excellent Gordon, thank you for pointing it out. your query is in fact the fastest.

Answer (score 1):

The `AND` will need both the condition to be satisfied at the same time and can not find a row with 2 different condition.

You can use `exits` to do it

```
select t1.sampleID 
from QS_base  t1
where 
t1.rs = 'rs123' AND t1.A1 = 'C' AND t1.A2 = 'C' 
and exists
(
 select 1 from QS_base t2 where t1.sampleID = t2.sampleID
 and t2.rs = 'rs345' AND t2.A1 = 'C' AND t2.A2 = 'C'
)
```

Comment: this works. thank you. now supposing I wanted to match an extra condition (eg. (rs = 'rs678' AND A1 = 'C' AND A2 = 'C'), could you provide an example pls

Comment: just add another and at the end as `and exists ( select 1 from QS_base t3 where t1.sampleID = t3.sampleID) and t3.rs = 'rs678' AND t3.A1 = 'C' AND t3.A2 = 'C' )`

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for samples where rs is both 'rs123' and 'rs345'. The query only looks at rows individually.

Answer (score 0):

You have excluding conditions in the second example. The where clause:

```
WHERE (rs = 'rs123' AND A1 = 'C' AND A2 = 'C')  AND (rs = 'rs345' AND A1 = 'C' AND A2 = 'C')
```

cloud be written as:

```
WHERE rs = 'rs123' AND rs = 'rs345' AND A1 = 'C' AND A2 = 'C'
```

rs cannot be equal to rs123 and rs345 at the sime time. :)

As for the second part of Your question, yes it certainly can return result that You need. Just write:

```
WHERE (rs = 'rs123' AND A1 = 'C' AND A2 = 'C')
```

I assume You have additional requirements on this query, if so, please state them in You post.

Comment: the aim is to return all column (sampleID) where the columns rs, A1 and A2 match the pattern specified